# What kind of studies are this?

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory, random-graphs

at this [link](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/mod1/) there are quite a number of images reporting different patterns inside a circle: what kind of studies are this and does this belongs to a specific branch of the mathematics ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what they're doing is making graphs on with vertex set $\{0,\ldots ,n-1\}$ and edges defined by $\{x,\;f(x)\bmod{n}\}$, where each image corresponds to a different $f(x)$.  I would say the area of math here is number theory, just represented in an interesting way using graphs.

There may also be some of them where the vertex set is a large sampling of points from $[0,1)$, with $f(x)$ taken $\bmod 1$.

Comment: so the circle line is basically substituting the line of the real numbers ?

Comment: @user2485710 No, it would be $\{0,\ldots , n-1\}$ arranged in a circle (or in the second case, the sampling of points from $[0,1)$ arranged in a circle).

Comment: ok, but this helps you with what ? How to fruitfully implement something that uses this studies ?

Comment: @user2485710 Honestly they're probably just made to look cool.  Maybe the author was just being exploratory and seeing if he could find something interesting to prove.

Comment: You can ask him, by the way, it has his name: Simon Plouffe. He's a mathematician, website is [here](http://www.plouffe.fr/).